# How can I make SWAPS using FPML

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, swap, fpml

I want to design an efficient & flexible architecture to process Swaps based on a standard financial protocol - FPML (Financial products markup language).

I've researched on internet but didn't find much information. The definitions which I found are:

SWAP (definition):

> ​Swap refers to an exchange of one financial instrument for another between the parties concerned. This exchange takes place at a predetermined time, as specified in the contract.

FPML​:

> FPML (Financial products Markup Language) is the open source XML
>   standard for electronic dealing and processing of OTC derivatives. It
>   establishes the industry protocol for sharing information on, and
>   dealing in, financial derivatives and structured products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have got an assignment to complete. I had almost the same thing to build using c# and ms sql.

Few important links and mentioning which will help you.

Few References

http://www.fpml.org

http://www.investinganswers.com/financial-dictionary/optionsderivatives/interest-rate-swap-2252

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/swap.asp

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swap_(finance)

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/equityswap.asp

http://www.fpml.org/documents/FpML5-products-framework.pdf

http://www.investopedia.com/articles/optioninvestor/07/swaps.asp

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following stackoverflow posting: http://bit.ly/python-xml-swap